# How do I remove the CSS:Float property when image occupies >50% of screen

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, css-float, image-resizing

I have a mostly responsive Wordpress website with some images aligned either left or right. I want to remove the float property of these aligned images when they occupy a percentage of the screen (about %50) as it's causing issues with how the text is displayed (one word next to an image, then followed by the rest of the paragraph).

When I remove the float property I get exactly the behaviour I want from the website, but I don't know how to set it so it only triggers under these conditions.

Below is the CSS for the affected images.

```
img {
display: inline-block;
max-width: 100%;
}

.align-right {
float: right;
}
```

Comment: You would need javascript to make the calculation or use a media query for when a break point is hit if all your images are the same width

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript to calculate the width of window and compare to width of image.

```js
function myFunction() {
            var img = document.getElementById("Image");

            var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

            if (img.offsetWidth > window.innerWidth / 2) {
                div.style.cssFloat = "none";
            }
            else {
                div.style.cssFloat = "right";
            }
        }
```

```css
img {
            display: inline-block;
            max-width: 100%;
            width: 400px;
            background-color: lightgrey;
            height: 200px;
        }
```

```html
<body onresize="myFunction()" onload="myFunction()">
    <div>
        <img id="Image" src="" alt="Image" />
        <div id="myDiv" style="background-color: lightgrey;">
            Hello This is Div.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Show the result in full page for your better results.